# Does magit when using ediff have a means for moving on the next file when there are multiple files to be diffed?

Tags: magit, ediff

I am using `ediff` to get side by side diffs with `magit` and there seems to be no way to move to the next pair of files, after diffing the current file.

For instance if I use `vimdiff` for `git diff`, after using `:qa` to close the diffs on the current file the next change file is brought up to be diffed.

Does the ediff have a method of doing that?

Currently it looks like have to close the current window, return to the magit status window and select the next file to be diffed.

Comment: I have opened a feature request - [Enable ediff to view the changed files one after the other without having to return to the status window first](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3164)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Ediff myself, but I believe to remember that it has such a feature but that it depends on the caller feeding it the necessary information up front. Magit doesn't do that.

Please open a feature request.

Comment: I have opened a feature request: [Enable ediff to view the changed files one after the other without having to return to the status window first](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3164)